# What are the possible causes for the segfault error codes

Tags: c++, linux, memory, segmentation-fault

I encounter a segfault issue recently, it is hit when invoking the delete method. I have examined the code in depth and eliminate the possibility of deleting a null pointer, or multiple deletes, or out-of-bound(The memory allocated is large enough to hold the content that is written to it afterward). This issue can be reproduced, each time it segfaults in the same place.

I am running out of idea what may cause this issue. I wonder whether it is possible to get some clues from the error code I get, such as:-
segfault at xxxxxxxxxxxxxx rip xxxxxxxxxxxxxx rsp xxxxxxxxxxxxxx error 4

I search over the net for quite a long time, only get the useful following info from stackoverflow:-

"The error code is just the architectural error code for page faults and seems to be architecture specific. They are often documented in arch/*/mm/fault.c in the kernel source. My copy of Linux/arch/i386/mm/fault.c has the following definition for error_code:

```
bit 0 == 0 means no page found, 1 means protection fault
bit 1 == 0 means read, 1 means write
bit 2 == 0 means kernel, 1 means user-mode
```

"

Here is my question:-
What is the possible causes of error code 4(My platform is RHEL5 64bit, x86_64)? Is there any way to tell the possible causes from the error code?

Any other advice about how to diagnose this kind of issue is also appreciated!

Comment: Run your program under `valgrind`.

Comment: Deleting a null pointer isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given the documentation from `arch/i386/mm/fault.c` that you supply, an error code of 4 corresponds to "user-mode read of a page not found." Binary representation of code 4 = 100, where bit 2 is the most-significant (leftmost) bit.

This chimes with the most common cause of receiving a `SIGSEGV` upon a `delete`: a double-free (attempting to free a pointer that's already been freed).  However, any heap corruption (say, by double-freeing something else or a buffer overflow / out-of-bounds error somewhere else) could be the cause.

Try running the code (compiled with debugging symbols) under `valgrind` or running with a debugging version of the memory allocation routines (set `MALLOC_CHECK_` to 1 or 2 within the environment before your binary is run), two different approaches which both attempt to catch these errors and report them to you as soon as they're made.

`valgrind` is exhaustive in its memory model and, with the proper amount of checking turned-on, *will almost certainly* locate the source of the problem.

`MALLOC_CHECK_` is internal to glibc and, like most other memory debug instrumentation tools that aren't `valgrind`, it can only catch certain types of relatively common errors and detect heap corruption in some cases. There are a host of other tools like `MALLOC_CHECK_` out there (such as Electric Fence), but the former is already built into your C library, and the others will, at best, require that their library (which contains `malloc` and `free` overrides, mainly) be dynamically linked ahead of the C library with the use of `LD_PRELOAD`.

Note that using C++ `delete` upon a null pointer isn't technically a problem, so you can scratch that one off your checklist (as I'd guess you probably already have, by modifying the code to explicitly check before deleting).

MORE DETAILS:

The error code corresponding to "user-mode read of a page not found" implies that a pointer to memory (some 32/64-bit number referring to somewhere in your virtual address space) was dereferenced (i.e., some code tried to read the value at the virtual memory address that the pointer held) but the kernel page tables indicate that the virtual address refers to a page [of memory] that has either not been mapped into your process or has been unmapped from your process since that pointer was valid.  Aside from the obvious ways to imagine this happening, it can happen indirectly due to a corrupted heap (which contains all sorts of book-keeping information behind-the-scenes): for example, pointer arithmetic may be done on the value you pass to `delete` with another, earlier-corrupted pointer internal to the heap which then leads to an invalid value sitting in a pointer, just waiting for code to try and use it.

In other words, the kernel error code really doesn't help you much in common debugging scenarios.

I assume you've run your program under `gdb` and just set a breakpoint a few lines before the crash to observe the values of the pointer being deleted and the rest of the surrounding state.

EDIT:

Removed erroneous `-g2` reference when I apparently meant `MALLOC_CHECK_`. Added further diagnosis questions and explanations for you.

Comment: Do you mean if the cause is located somewhere else, add -g2 switch when compile the code may force the program to abort earlier once the error is made? But as far as I know, -g2 switch will add symbols to the binary, never heard it will do such kind of checking, is there any reference to this?

Comment: I know that, we can export MALLOC_CHECK_ to force the program to abort earlier when there is memory corruption in the process. I think if this issue is caused by memory corrupt somewhere else, this would be also be a good choice, what's your opinion? BTW, in my case, I cannot access the environment freely, and the issue cannot be reproduced in my environment(also not 100% reproducible in the environment in question). so Valgrind is not a good choice. I need to find some simple and feasible way to do so.

Comment: @user1137890 I mean, if you add `-g2` (as opposed to just `-g` which turns on debug symbols) when compiling your code, GCC will turn on its debugging heap allocator and a variety of other runtime error detection instrumentation options. This will do something similar to the `MALLOC_CHECK_` you describe, which may be a fine option as well, and you should try it too. If the bug's not yet reproduceable, then that's all the more reason to suspect heap corruption, which can in most cases be detected at runtime at the first point of memory error (with such tools) rather than long after corruption.

Comment: @user1137890 You're right about the default level being 2. I'll update the answer. I was wrong, and I can't find reference to what I was thinking `-g2` delivered, in terms of built-in compiler support for memory debugging. I may have been thinking of `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, which turns on [libstdc++ debug mode](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt03ch17s03.html). That mainly turns on runtime algorithm and iterator (container bounds) checking.

Comment: @user1137890 And, yes, it was `MALLOC_CHECK_` to which I was referring originally.  Have you used this?  I still don't understand why you can't use `valgrind`.  The beauty of `valgrind` is that it will *make* your problem reproducible.

Comment: The environment that reproduction can be observe is product environment, valgrind will affect the performance. And in my local environment the issue does not recur.